# PHP Interface Implement - Unsure of correct implementation

Tags: php

I've been the interface below and I can't get it to work with the class that implements it - can anyone advise what is wrong with myClass to get it to work with the interface? thanks

```
 <?php


      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Works here: needed to change the syntax slightly. https://eval.in/610995

Comment: does this code compile?? Because `$this` is utilizing a non object context.

Comment: can you tell me the run time error? I'm using phpfiddle and I dont' get an error? thankyou

Comment: @Adam, example here: https://eval.in/611002